# Install native messaging host for a mac app

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, mac-app-store, chrome-native-messaging

I have built a mac osx app with Swift and a chrome extension which communicates with the app to deliver its service. However in order for the extension to be able to talk to the native app I needed to create a .json file under

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts`

Now I would like to automatically create this file under the given folder when the user installs my app, otherwise the extension cannot communicate with the app. How do I best go about this? The mac app doesn't have access to the `.../Application Support/Google/Chrome/...` folder since it runs in its sandbox environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension with native messaging host also (github.com/ncssar/gpsio - still trying to figure out some mac host permission issues so the mac support is not published yet but the mac installer does work).

I used the recommended built-in mac command 'pkgbuild' to create .pkg files, which normally open with the built-in 'installer' application.  While the .pkg is mainly just an archive of files, it can also run scripts that are built into the .pkg file using pkgbuild.  The 'postinstall' script was the key.

[Here's the gitbub issue comment](https://github.com/ncssar/gpsio/issues/27#issuecomment-981101490) where I collected the few good resources I could find about this - especially the pdf.

The postinstall script creates the manifests on the fly.  Because it's run from within the built-in installer application, it should prompt you for the password to create all these files and such.

To help the workflow of creating the .pkg file, I made a little wrapper script that I just source each time I need to rebuild it.  It assembles all the various parts into the pkgbuild root dir, then calls pkgbuild:

```
/bin/mkdir pkgbuild_root
/bin/mkdir pkgbuild_root/host
/bin/mkdir pkgbuild_scripts
/bin/cp -f ../host/gpsio-host.py pkgbuild_root/host
/bin/cp -f ../host/gpsio-host.ini pkgbuild_root/host
/bin/cp -f install-gpsio.py pkgbuild_scripts/postinstall
/bin/cp -f prerequisites/common/*.* pkgbuild_root
/bin/cp -f prerequisites/mac/*.* pkgbuild_root
pkgbuild --identifier gpsio.pkg --root pkgbuild_root --scripts pkgbuild_scripts --install-location /Library/gpsio-install-tmp gpsio.pkg
# /bin/rm -rf pkgbuild_root
# /bin/rm -rf pkgbuild_scripts
```

One key point here is that the pkg extraction target is a temp dir; it's not the final native host dir.  The script takes care of making and populating the host dir - both from static files in the .pkg archive, and from generated manifest files.

Comment: This will not work if I want to deploy my app to the macOS App Store, correct?

Comment: Sorry, not sure, I haven't tried on the app store.